# Regex search substring

Tags: regex

I have a question on how to search for a substring using Regexp.

Say, I have a "base" string, such as:
**image height=X width=Y end**

Both height and width in the above "base" string are assigned integer values that vary, i.e.:
image height=15 width=20 end
image height=10 width=10 end
image height=20 width=5 end

So my question is whether it's possible to fetch ***width value*** using canonical regex given that the first part of the substring effectively changes?

Comment: _given that the first part of the substring effectively changes_ <- could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I'm not sure about the purpose. What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regexp `/width=(\d+)/` should do it:

```js
var strs = ['image height=15 width=20 end this is another width=123', 'width=200 and image height=10 width=10 end', 'image height=20 width=5 end'];

var widths = strs.map(function(str) {
   var matches = str.match(/\bimage height=\d+ width=(\d+) end\b/);
   return matches && matches.length > 1 ? parseInt(matches[1], 10) : null;
});

document.write(widths);
```

Comment: You should put `\b` before `width`, so it doesn't match something like `contentwidth=123`

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to actually have this follow the exact "base" string format? Assuming "width" is present elsewhere in the source text, this would return all such values, whereas I only need those between the "image height=15 width=" and "end".

Comment: Indeed - see edit. I've added to the example strings width=* before and after  respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ori Drori is correct if you don't require the exact form you specified. If you do, you could use this:

```js
var strs = ['image height=15 width=20 end', 'image height=10 width=10 end', 'image height=20 width=5 end'];

var widths = strs.map(function(str) {
   var matches = str.match(/image\ height=\d+\ width=(\d+)\ end/);

   return matches.length > 1 ? parseInt(matches[1], 10) : null;
});

document.write(widths);
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code returns parameters for "height" and not "width". Can you correct that, please?

Comment: @Alex Ah yeah, it actually gets both but I forgot to mention that. I'll fix the answer.